# How to ignore a dot (.) in regex?

Tags: regex

I have this:

```
(adrian)(@mazur.com)|(^(adrian)\+(.*)@mazur.com$)
```

It matches these only partially:

```
adrian@mazur.com
adrian+whatever@mazur.com
adrian+what.ev.er@mazur.com
a.d.r.i.a.n@mazur.com
a.d.r.i.a.n+whatever@mazur.com
a..drian@mazur.com
```

They also can't match those:

```
patryk@mazur.com
patryk+whatever@mazur.com
patryk+what.ev.er@mazur.com
p.a.t.r.y.k@mazur.com
p.a.t.r.y.k+whatever@mazur.com
p..adtryk@mazur.com
p.dra..us...@mazur.com
```

or other like danuta, micheal, ryan, sean etc.

How do I make it ignore the dot (.) between my name?
I use this tool to test the regex: http://74.50.60.193/ it's http://www.rubular.com/ but it doesn't resolve for me so I put IP too.

Comment: Check for optional `.` characters.

Comment: Remove the dots before or if you have time to loose write: `a\.*d\.*r\.*i\.*a\.*n`

Comment: specify which entries are valid within your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the current answers have logical flaws in their patterns.

Based on the OP's question combined with the OP's ongoing comments combined with the OP's previous question, valid strings will:

1. Start with `adrian` which *may* have zero or more dots before or after each/every letter in the name.
2. The `adrian` substring *may optionally* be followed by a plus sign then zero or more non-white-space characters.

This is what you are looking for: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XOSDEr/3))

```
^(\.*a\.*d\.*r\.*i\.*a\.*n\.*(?:\+[^@\s]*)?)(@mazur\.com)$
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be the best one. Thank you very much. Also thanks for the demo website. I will use it more to learn about regex so the next time I will need something like this I will be able to do it myself.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this although it isn't the best solution (you will also need global flag to capture all matches):

```
(a\.*?d\.*?r\.*?i\.*?a\.*?n)\+?(.*)(@mazur\.com)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
[^ \n]{1,}(@mazur.com)
```

This says to accept anything except a space or a new line, from 1 to many times, and then your website name. I changed it from 0 to 1 because I figured nobody would have an email without something leading in front of it.

But, if it cant match anything except adrian...you could do this. Not such an elegant approach, but this will solve your problem.

```
a(\.+)?d(\.+)?r(\.+)?i(\.+)?a(\.+)?n(.+)?(@mazur\.com)
```

Comment: That almost works but whatever means just that. Any thing after + needs  to be accepted. How can I make it work?

Comment: Ill update the last one to accept numbers too. Comment more test cases that dont work and Ill make it work.

Comment: Actually, I have a better idea. Updating the answer now

Comment: That would be great but it can't match anything other then adrian. I updated the first post to account for that. Sorry. I should have pointed that out sooner.

Comment: Are those updated cases the only other ones it cannot match?

Comment: No. It can only match adrian in this case, no one else. This is because other people will have a separate rule so one rule per name/user. I will use this to configure forwarding so I can't have the same regex rule matching more then one name.

Comment: Okay, I believe I have solved it! Let me know, and please accept the answer if I did... My answer is very similar to @G.Margaritis too. Did not realize.

Comment: Thank you. It's not as elegant as I'd like it to be but it works. The first rule you proposed will also solve another one of my problem which is catch-all. I selected your answer as solution instead of the one proposed by G.Margaritis because of it, even though he was first.

Comment: One last question. Is there a possibility to not accept anything other then + sign after the last letter? Right know something like adrian.patryk@mazur.com is also true from this rule

Comment: Would cases like this show up too? adrian.p.a.t.ryk@mazur.com

Comment: I've solved it with this: (a\.*?d\.*?r\.*?i\.*?a\.*?n)(@mazur\.com)|(a\.*?d\.*?r\.*?i\.*?a\.*?n)(\+(.*))

Comment: Haha cool. It doesnt match your test cases though. Im happy you figured it out!